# Inserting (DATE(now)) in MySql using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert the current date to the database using prepared statements (PHP).
This is the code that I am currently using

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $user_name = $_SESSION['customer_name'];
      $user_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
      $get_text1 = $_POST['title'];
      $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,(DATE(now)))");
      $sql->bind_param("isss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1);
      $sql->execute(); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did it work? Did you get an error? Why not just `NOW()`?

Comment: @tadman It does not insert any value

Comment: @tadman NOW() seems to work, however I just need the date without the time

Comment: Is this going into a `DATE` field? If so it should get stripped.

Comment: Just use [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Database Side** (recommended choice)

You may use curdate() to do the job which is actually available in MySQL, in that case simply change these lines :

```
$sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,(DATE(now)))");
$sql->bind_param("isss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1);
```

to

```
 $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,curdate())");
      $sql->bind_param("isss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1);
```

**Solution 2: Application Side**

You may also use the application side date (the date of the web server which runs the PHP), in that case you can use the date() function. Such as date('Y-m-d').
Hence , try changing these 2 lines:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,(DATE(now)))");
$sql->bind_param("isss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1);
```

to

```
$currentdate=date('Y-m-d');
$sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param("issss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1, $currentdate);
```

In modern servers which have NTP enabled and running, the two time should be the same if they are using the same locale.

However, if NTP are not applied in both servers, the datetime data in the two servers can be different in that case you have to decide which one to use. (better use the solution 1). Solution 2 is added here just to show that in case there is a piece of data which is not available in database side, you can switch to use application side as a resort.

Comment: It's not necessary nor recommended to do the date part on the application side. There can be differences between application server time and database server time. Use `DATE(NOW())` if necessary, or `NOW()` if truncation is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following. Instead of binding use `NOW()` in SQL to get the current date.

```
   <?php
     if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $user_name = $_SESSION['customer_name'];
      $user_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
      $get_text1 = $_POST['title'];
      $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT into free_ad(user_id, user_name, user_email,title,timenow) values 
     (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
      $sql->bind_param("isss",$user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$get_text1);
      $sql->execute(); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although this is going to work, I will not need the additional 'time' that comes along with the date using NOW()

Comment: Do you have a `DATE` column?

Comment: @abbaszaidi Then replace `NOW` with `CURDATE`